# Suggestion box not showing for nearest input

Tags: php, jquery

I cannot seem to get my suggestion box to show for the nearest input after adding more inputs dynamically.

The below code is where I am currently, I can see the suggestion box for a new input and add to that new input but if I go back to edit the input data the suggestion box fails to show.

```
<div id="tester"></div>
<button id="add_test">ADD</button>



$(document).ready(function() {

$("#add_test").on("click", function() {
    var input = '<div class="flavhey"><div class="flavourInput"><input class="ftext form-control flavour-name-input" type="text" name="flav-name-input" value="" placeholder="Flavour Name" /><div class="suggestion-box"></div></div></div>';
    $('#tester').append(input);
});


$(document).on('keyup', '.flavhey input', function(e){


    var token = '<?php echo json_encode($token); ?>';
    var search = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "controllers/recipeControl.php",
        data: { token: token, search: search },
        beforeSend: function(){
            $(".flavour-name-input").css("background","#FFF no-repeat 165px");
            $(".suggestion-box").css("background","#FFF no-repeat 165px");
    },
    success: function(data){


        $('.flavhey input').closest('flavourInput input').next('.suggestion-box').show();
        $('.flavhey input').next('.suggestion-box').html(data);
        $(".suggestion-box").css("background","#FFF");
    }
    });
    return false;
});
$(document).on("click",".search-flavour",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

        $(this).closest('.flavourInput').find('.flavour-name-input').val($(this).text());

        $('.suggestion-box').hide();
    return false;

if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest' && isset($_POST['token']) 
        && json_decode($_POST['token']) === $_SESSION['token']){
            $search = $_POST['search'];
            $html = '<ul>';
            $content = $flavours->getAllFlavoursSearch($search);
            foreach ($content as $con) {
                $html .= '<li class="search-flavour"><b>'.$con['flavour_name'].'</b> - <i>'.$con['flavour_company_name'].'</i></li>';
            }
            $html .= '</ul>';
            echo $html;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ok short version:**

Use `var box = $(e.target).next(".suggestion-box");` to aquire a reference to the correct suggestion box in the `success` handler of the ajax request.

---

**Long version:**
I replaced the php parts with static placeholders to get a runnable example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#add_test").on("click", function() {
    var input = '<div class="flavhey"><div class="flavourInput"><input class="ftext form-control flavour-name-input" type="text" name="flav-name-input" value="" placeholder="Flavour Name" /><div class="suggestion-box"></div></div></div>';
    $('#tester').append(input);
  });


  $(document).on('keyup', '.flavhey input', function(e) {
    var token = "[token]";
    var search = $(this).val();

    var box = $(e.target).next(".suggestion-box");
    box.show();
    box.html("TestData");
    box.css("background", "#FFF");

    return false;
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".search-flavour", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.flavourInput').find('.flavour-name-input').val($(this).text());
    $('.suggestion-box').hide();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tester"></div>
<button id="add_test">ADD</button>

<ul>
  <li class="search-flavour">
    <b>flavour_name_1</b> - <i>flavour_company_name_1</i>
  </li>
  <li class="search-flavour">
    <b>flavour_name_2</b> - <i>flavour_company_name_2</i>
  </li>
  <li class="search-flavour">
    <b>flavour_name_3</b> - <i>flavour_company_name_3</i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now being able to execute your code I was able to reproduce the described error. 
**Please try to provide a runnable example next time.**

I realized that your box was only appearing once because the call to `.show()` wasn't working at all. 
It was visible from the beginning just without any content so you couldn't see it, then after setting `html()` it had content and it looked like the call to `show()` worked as intended.

Afer you clicked on a `.search-flavour` all boxes were correctly hidden and thus never appeared again.

So to fix this, replace the success handler of the ajax request with this:

```
success: function(data){
    // e.target is the currently active input element
    var box = $(e.target).next(".suggestion-box");
    box.show()
       .html(data)
       .css("background", "#FFF");
}
```

Comment: Amazing, thankyou so much!!! You just saved me from more hours of frustration and made my day, I can award the 50 points in 19 hours, thanks again.

Comment: This works perfect on desktop, can you see a reason why it wouldn't work on mobile?

Comment: Fixed it `$(document).on("click touchstart",".search-flavour",function() {` Thanks again

Comment: The above fix didn't work as planned so i wrapped the data in a `a` tag instead